# If PictureBox Clicked Event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program a matching game. My idea is:

(1). When a certain `pictureBox1` is clicked, it becomes invisible

(2). A `MessageBox` shows up, prompting *"Pick another box."*

(3). Finally, I need to program an `if/else` statement where if `pictureBox13` is clicked it becomes invisible; `else`, (if another `pictureBox` is clicked) a `MessageBox` prompts *"Try again."* And both picture boxes become invisible, but I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
    // Program From Below
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Now Pick Another Hidden Picture!");
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        if (pictureBox13_Click)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Great!");
            pictureBox13.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Try Again!");
        }


    }
```

There is a red squiggly line under `if (pictureBox13_Click)`

Comment: `if(pictureBox13_Click)`?! Probably It is name of a method and not a Boolean variable. Just make each `PictureBox` invisible on click.

Comment: Each PictureBox would need its own click event code, or you create a general click method that all of the PictureBox controls use, and you determine which PictureBox was clicked by examining the sender parameter.

Comment: In addition to previous comment: I think you will have to cast the sender to PictureBox.. Then you will be able to check its ID or name property..

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if every PictureBox had it's a state, that you would then manipulate using a Click_Event. Microsoft has a comprehensive tutorial for a matching game here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553235.aspx

Comment: Yes, this article looks like a good answer and in particular step#4 on event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for comments! I was wondering, however, if if/else statements could be used as: if something was clicked, then something happens, else... Don't worry about what's between. Just need to know how to program the "if clicked" statement.

Answer (score 1):

As other suggested, you can use same event handler for all your pictureBoxes and cast `sender` to `PictureBox` to see what PB was clicked :

```
List<string> selectedPictureBoxes;

public MyForm()  // ctor
{
   selectedPictureBoxes = new List<string>();

   foreach(Control c in this.Controls) 
      if(c is PictureBox) c.Click += pictureBox_Click;
}

private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox _clicked = sender as PictureBox;

    if(!selectedPictureBoxes.Contains(_clicked.Name))
       selectedPictureBoxes.Add(_clicked.Name);
    else ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `int` for the selected boxes (in this example, box1 and box2) which are both set to 0 and then create an on click event which sets the int to the clicked box.

```
if(box1 != 0) 
    {
        box2 = 'insert selected box number'
    }
    else
    {
        box1 = 'insert selected box number'
    }
```

After two boxes have been selected, both `integers` can be set to false, this allows for you to use a `switch` instead of `if`, which could shorten the code substantially if a separate `if` statement is required for each pair of pictures.